# Not able to show a map on a mobilefirst application

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, ibm-mobilefirst

I wanna show a google map in my mobilefirst application. I know that mobilefirst applications are single DOM, and the map is supposed to be shown in the second page (accessible by a click on a button in my index.html)

Any help?

Comment: When you ask questions on stack overflow you are expect to provide your implementation so that it could be debugged. Provide your MobileFirst project and always mention which platform you are developing for.

Answer (score 0):

You can take as an implementation example the following app: https://www.dropbox.com/s/htsrrlb5yaglwgl/MultiPagesWithGMaps.zip?dl=0

It shows how to navigate to a second "page" (a different div in the app essentially) and then click a button in order to display a Google Maps-based map.

The project is from Worklight 6.1, but will successfully migrate in a MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 Studio.